# How to find where the dependencies used in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-management

I have a dependencies conflict shows I used `com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0`
, and I find the `com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0` used in dependencies tree, but I haven't used it in my code, Where does the `com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0` come from and how can I find where it used in the project? Thanks first.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
}
```

dependencies tree:

```
releaseUnitTestCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: releaseUnitTest
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0 -> 11.6.0


releaseUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Resolved configuration for runtime for variant: releaseUnitTest
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0 -> 11.6.0
```

Comment: This is not the only `build.gradle` file you have. There should be another module, that you are attaching to your project and that module should import `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` dependency.

Comment: @azizbekian, Thanks,There is only one module 'app' and the there is only gradle path and  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' in project 'build.gradle'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check project's entire dependency tree invoke `gradle dependencies --configuration compile` 
You have to be using another module which is using this dependency.

you can force specific version with

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0'
  }
}
or
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0') {
    force = true
}
```

Comment: Hi, There is still another problem, that I used implementation and `gradle dependencies --configuration compile`  or `gradle dependencies --configuration implementation ` doesn't work